# link at end of video (not youtube hosted)

Tags: javascript, html, video

I want to play a video on a website that isn't hosted by youtube and I want to have a link at the end of the video.
The text for this link is on the last image of the video, so a transparent overlay or so would work.
I am learning and Javascript and have come up with 'onended' and wanted to then show a transparent image OVER the video and link this image up to the contact page.

Here the code for the video itself:

```
<video id="greenhat_video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="350" height="200" onended="myFunction()" poster="http://www.greenhat.org.uk/video/poster.png" data-setup='{}'>
         <source src="http://www.greenhat.org.uk/video/What-Do-Green-Hat Do-FINAL4-GH-Web.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
```

Your browser does not support the video tag.

Here the javascript code to call onended the transparent, linked image:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
document.write("<a href="http://www.greenhat.org.uk/request_information.html"> <img src="http://www.greenhat.org.uk/video/overlay_transparentB.gif" /> </a>");
                 });
            </script>
```

This is the overlay I had constructed but fail to call
     
      </a>
    </div>-->

Any advise how I can now call the image as transparent link onended video would be much appreciated!